Problem of Fourier transform and compact operator
Problem:
Is the Fourier transform $F(f(x))=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(y)e^{-ixy}dy$ a compact operator in the case of $F:L_1\left ( \mathbb {R} \right )\to \mathrm{BC}\left ( \mathbb{R}\right )$. $\mathrm{BC}$ - Bounded and continuous
My attempt to solve:
Let's take a sequence of functions $e^{-n|x|}$. They all lie in $L_1$. The Fourier transform of them is (up to a universal coefficient) the Cauchy distribution $n/(n^2 + y^2)$, the $C$-norm of this is simply the maximum value, it is achieved at the point $y = 0 $ and equals $1/n$. But this does not give anything, there the norm was $2/n$, in the image it became proportional to $1/n$
How, in this case, can one reason and prove whether an operator is compact or non-compact?

I just realized the sequence you provided actually already does the job. Let $f_n = ne^{-n|x|}$. As you already observed, $\|f_n\|_{L^1} = 2$, so if $F$ is compact, we must have for a subsequence $f_{n_k}$, $F(f_{n_k})$ converges uniformly. But $F(f_n) = \frac{2n^2}{n^2 + y^2}$, which converges pointwise to the constant function $2$. Thus $F(f_{n_k}) \to 2$ uniformly. However, $\|F(f_n) - 2\|_\infty = 2$ for all $n$, a contradiction. Thus, $F$ is not compact.
